# render :new not going to the right place after a validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a 'new' form that gets validated in a post model. When the validator kicks in, it renders incorrectly.

The new post page path is at '/posts/new'

On validation, the new post page path is at '/posts' .. I need it to go back to '/posts/new'.

This is my controller:

```
def create
 @post = current_user.posts.build(params[:post])
 if @post.save
   redirect_to public_post_page_path(@post.public_url)
 else 
   render :action => :new
 end
end
```

I have a feeling it might have to do with my form. So here is the formtastic first line:

```
<%= semantic_form_for [:student, post], :html => {:id => "post_form"} do |form| %>
```

Answer (score 14):

This is the correct behavior from rails.

In the create action it simply renders the "new" view file. As such the url will be /posts but the view will correctly display the form. There is nothing wrong with this behavior; and in general rails convention is good form. Also the built in rails errors work if you just render new; however if you redirect they won't display.

If you really feel like you want to go back to that url you need to use:

```
redirect_to
```

instead of render.

Comment: I want to display the errors, so it needs to be render. The reason I need it to go back to /posts/new is a little complex. But basically, in controller for 'def new', I check the twitter validation for the user to determine whether or not to show parts of the form. When it goes to '/posts', I lose this validation.

I guess then the question is, is there a way to reload the code in 'new' controller after render?

Comment: Create a private controller method to do your setup for new, call it from new and from create before it renders new

Comment: @Marc Rails, by convention does a `POST` to /posts for creating. You can always violate this convention by posting to /posts/new.

Comment: I followed house9 advice. Did this 'before_filter :check_twitter, :only => [:new, :edit, :create, :update]'

Comment: This is an important answer, because if you're using Rspec and have something like this: page.current_url.should == "http://www.example.com/accounts/new", the test will fail, despite the actual behavior is that at the url /accounts, the "new" is actually being rendered.

Answer (score 0):

If validation fails, user should see the form with the errors and stay at `/posts/new`. That's what you want, right?

There's a simple way to achieve this.

Set `remote: true` on the form to prevent the url from advancing. Handle `ajax:success` to replace the form on the page with the newly rendered one.

```
$('form[data-remote=true]').on 'ajax:success', (e, data, status, xhr) ->
  if isHTML(data)
    thisForm = "form[id=#{@getAttribute('id')}]"
    $(thisForm).replaceWith $(data).find(thisForm)
```

`isHtml()` function is from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458876/check-if-a-string-is-html-or-not).