# Select Tag, undefined method `map'

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a subscriptions form where I am trying to set the plan the user has chosen, the business they would like to associate with the subscription and the payment details. In my form I use a select tag to display a list of all of the businesses and it displays properly in my view but upon save I get the following error:

```
undefined method `map' for #<Business:0x007f8ea7955b90>
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<div class="field">
  <%= select_tag :business_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@businesses, "id", "name") %>
</div>
```

**subscriptions_controller.rb**

```
...

def new
  @subscription = Subscription.new
  @plan = Plan.find(params["plan_id"])
  @businesses = Business.all
end

def create
  @subscription = Subscription.new(subscription_params)
  raise "Please, check subscription errors" unless @subscription.valid?
  @subscription.process_payment
  @subscription.save
  redirect_to @subscription, notice: 'Subscription was successfully created.'
rescue => e
  flash[:error] = e.message
  render :new
end

private

  def set_subscription
    @subscription = Subscription.find(params[:id])
  end

  def subscription_params
    params.require(:subscription).permit(:plan_id, :business_id, :card_token, :coupon)
  end
```

Am I setting up the select_tag properly? Do I need to fix my create method? Looked at other solutions on SO with little success.

[image]

Comment: Could you add some lines from the top of your error stack trace? Up to ten lines ought to be enough, I'd think.

Comment: @amar47shah does the above image help?

Comment: Yes, that does help. It looks like the `create` action attempted to render the `new` template again, probably because the new subscription was not valid. Note that `render :new` doesn't call the `new` action in the controller. It's still hard for me to tell what's going on, though. It looks like the value of `@businesses` has changed from a collection to a single business, but I can't tell why. Just for debugging purposes, try setting `@businesses = Business.all` again in the `create` action's `rescue` block. Oh wait, now I have an idea!

Comment: @amar47shah I'm pulling in the business collection so a user can select from one of all my businesses they would like to start their subscription with.

Comment: @amar47shah do you still have an idea on how to fix?

Comment: Writing it up :) Unfortunately, I can't test it so I am trying to add helpful details. Just one moment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85038/discussion-between-amar47shah-and-justin-seidl).

Answer (score 0):

Rails instantiates a new controller for every request. There's some information about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14173269/2157021).

This means that any instance variables you've set in `new` won't be available when you process the POST in `create`.

In your case, you are rendering the `:new` template in the rescue block of the `create` action when the new subscription fails validation. You're only getting the error at this point, not when you originally access the form.

The problem is that `render :new` doesn't call the `new` action; it just renders the template. In the case where the subscription fails validation and the form is re-rendered, the `new` action has never been called by this controller instance, and the instance variables do not have the values expected by the template.

Try this instead of `render :new`:

```
redirect_to new_subscription_url
```

This will instantiate a new controller and call the `new` action, so that you will be starting over with a clean slate. The instance variables needed in the `new` template will be assigned the correct values before the template is rendered.

As an alternative, you could set the instance variables in the rescue block:

```
def create
...
rescue => e
  flash[:error] = e.message
  @businesses = Business.all
  render :new
end
```

Here's a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775599/render-new-not-going-to-the-right-place-after-a-validation) on Stack Overflow.

Hope that helps. Happy coding!